# Gerbera to transcode *.avi videos to h264 mkv?

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, h264, gerbera

I bought a Samsung SmartTV which do not support DIVX/XVID codec, so any of the old *.avi files I have work.

While I can always convert them, I have other devices in my DLNA network which supports them so I think a fast conversion is prefered.

I am trying to set transcode and file types as the following in `config.xml` (the relevant part):

```xml
<mappings>
    <extension-mimetype ignore-unknown="no">
        <map from="mp3" to="audio/mpeg"/>
        <map from="ogx" to="application/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogv" to="video/ogg"/>
        <map from="oga" to="audio/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogg" to="audio/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogm" to="video/ogg"/>
        <map from="asf" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
        <map from="asx" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
        <map from="wma" to="audio/x-ms-wma"/>
        <map from="wax" to="audio/x-ms-wax"/>
        <map from="wmv" to="video/x-ms-wmv"/>
        <map from="wvx" to="video/x-ms-wvx"/>
        <map from="wm" to="video/x-ms-wm"/>
        <map from="wmx" to="video/x-ms-wmx"/>
        <map from="m3u" to="audio/x-mpegurl"/>
        <map from="pls" to="audio/x-scpls"/>
        <map from="flv" to="video/x-flv"/>
        <map from="mkv" to="video/x-matroska"/>
        <map from="mka" to="audio/x-matroska"/>
        <map from="dsf" to="audio/x-dsd"/>
        <map from="dff" to="audio/x-dsd"/>
        <map from="wv" to="audio/x-wavpack"/>
        <map from="avi" to="video/divx"/>
    </extension-mimetype>
    <mimetype-upnpclass>
        <map from="audio/*" to="object.item.audioItem.musicTrack"/>
        <map from="video/*" to="object.item.videoItem"/>
        <map from="image/*" to="object.item.imageItem"/>
        <map from="application/ogg" to="object.item.audioItem.musicTrack"/>
    </mimetype-upnpclass>
    <mimetype-contenttype>
        <treat mimetype="audio/mpeg" as="mp3"/>
        <treat mimetype="application/ogg" as="ogg"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/ogg" as="ogg"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-flac" as="flac"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/flac" as="flac"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-ms-wma" as="wma"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-wavpack" as="wv"/>
        <treat mimetype="image/jpeg" as="jpg"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-mpegurl" as="playlist"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-scpls" as="playlist"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-wav" as="pcm"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/L16" as="pcm"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/x-msvideo" as="avi"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/mp4" as="mp4"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/mp4" as="mp4"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/x-matroska" as="mkv"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-matroska" as="mka"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-dsd" as="dsd"/>
    </mimetype-contenttype>
</mappings>
<transcoding enabled="yes">
    <mimetype-profile-mappings>
        <transcode mimetype="video/divx" using="ffmpegavi2h264"/>
    </mimetype-profile-mappings>
    <profiles>
        <profile name="ffmpegavi2h264" enabled="yes" type="external">
            <mimetype>video/x-matroska</mimetype>
            <accept-url>no</accept-url>
            <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
            <agent command="ffmpeg" arguments="-y -i %in -c:v libx264 -preset fast -c:a copy %out"/>
            <buffer size="4194304" chunk-size="524288" fill-size="1048576"/>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</transcoding>
```

While I can see when I select an avi file ffmpeg starts, TV says it is not a valid file for play.

What am I missing?

Thanks, as I don't know what else to try

Comment: I have transcode enabled="yes", I can't edit my own post, that's a typo

Comment: What is the TV model? Show info about your AVI input: `ffmpeg -i input.avi`

Comment: @StormByte Perhaps  `<mimetype>video/mp4</mimetype>` in your profile might make your tv happier?

Comment: It's a Samsung UE55NU7105, over the internet there are a lot of complaints of people about it not supporting DIVX/XVID codec, that's why I wanted to transcode all of them on the fly

Comment: @andrew.46 tried your suggestion, still says the selected file is not compatible :(

Comment: Hmmm... remaining culprit might be the audio codec, have you followed llogan's suggestion?

Comment: will try soon, sorry for my lack of response, had a little accident that made me afk

Answer (score 0):

You should add option for output format - `-f avi` (force format), i.e

```
...
<profile name="ffmpegavi2h264" enabled="yes" type="external">
    <mimetype>video/x-matroska</mimetype>
    <accept-url>no</accept-url>
    <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
    <agent command="ffmpeg" arguments="-y -i %in -c:v libx264 -preset fast -c:a copy -f avi %out"/>
    <buffer size="4194304" chunk-size="524288" fill-size="1048576"/>
</profile>
...
```

Gerbera `%out` substitute temporary file without extension, so ffmpeg produce error - `Unable to find a suitable output format without extension`

Comment: for "video/x-matroska" output format should be "-f matroska"